Why ABP recommends not to use Lazy Loading?
In the ABP documentation section (Entity Framework Core Integration Best Practices) it is stated:

Do not rely on lazy loading on the application development.

Why we shouldn't rely on lazy loading?


N + 1 query problem, 2) Do not allow async when lazy loading occurs 3) For lazy people :)


In almost all web applications lazy loading is explicitly disabled so if you depend on EF automagically loading a relate object when you access it, you'll get an error. Lazy loading is mainly used in desktop applications where a DbContext can be kept around for the lifetime of eg a form and used to load related data if a user wants to display more details. In a web app though, there's no state between requests so every request has to load all the data it needs every time, either from the database or the cache. Lazy loading would only delay loading data that has to be loaded anyway
